# Angularjs with GoogleBots using prerender.io

Tags: angularjs, apache, adsense

i am having many problems to get adsense in my web. I am trying to configure my virtualhost in order to use prerender.io when a bot is analyzing my web, but google bot (using search console) returns "Not accesible", and i don't find the solution.

This is the important code of my virtualHost (apache2):

```
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "(token)"

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest [NC,OR]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://www.ifmyweb.com/$2 [P,L]

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

In my mainApp.js:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

And in my index.html:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Does anyone know what am i doing wrong?? i have been testing changes for days and i don't get google bots load the web from prerender.

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: First, you publicly exposed your private Prerender.io token. You'll want to go into your Account and generate a new one so that no one can use it. Second, when I test your website I'm seeing a redirect happening so it's almost working correctly. It needs to be a proxy though, not a redirect. Can you email me at todd@prerender.io?

Comment: this question has nothing to do with angularJs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it solved and this was the answer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|Google(.*)|facebookexternalhit|visionutils|Facebot|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://www.ifmyweb.com/$2 [P,L]
```

Hope it can help anyone else :)